# How get visible / current viewcontroller in non-viewcontroller class? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, viewcontroller

I have information box object - "Info view". And I wanted to append this view to current VC view, sometimes directly in VC class sometimes outside VC class, ex. in my framework.

I don't want always pass current VC in method argument, like

```
class InfoView: UIView {

    /* Initialization methods */

    func show(viewController: ViewController) {

       /* some code */

        viewController.addSubview(self)
    }
}
```

I want get current VC directly in my "Info view" class:

```
class InfoView: UIView {

    /* Initialization methods */

    func show() {
        let viewController = /* need get current VC */

        /* some code */

        viewController.addSubview(self)
    }
}
```

`rootViewController` property in `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` returns current VC, but after transitions this VC not changed.

How I can get need get current VC?

Answer (score -1):

`rootViewController` is a good way to go. Your root VC is probably a navigation controller, so you could use something like this:

```
func currentVC() -> UIViewController? {
    guard let navigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else { return nil }
    return navigationController.viewControllers.last
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi Artem and DeyaEldeen,
If I am not wrong you want to access view controller on storyboard.

You can get instance of any view controller
Steps
1 set storyboard id for view controller in its Custom Class Attribute.
2 In your info view class

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MyViewcontroller *c = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewcontrollerStoryboardID"]
```

I hope it help you